# Is it possible to progressive play DRMed tracks

Tags: windows, audio, drm, wma

Is it possible to legally progressive play Windows Media DRM tracks as they are downloaded from a HTTP link?

I've managed to do this without DRM but someone here told me it wasn't possible with DRM.  Is this true?

And if so with what set of libraries or technologies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's possible and not illegal either. Normally, information about content encryption and actual encrypted content is kept separate in the same container. That is to say, metadata is not encrypted but content is. To support progressive download, the content is normally encrypted i small transferable ordered chunks. Your DRM client uses the metadata to locate a license server, next a license and content key is acquired from the license server. Next, your client downloads the content "chunk-per-chunk" ,decrypts each chunk, and renders it as a motion picture while it is downloading.

For information on SDK's, check out the different components [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/drm/components.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

Comment: Would you recommend a library or a set of technologies that does this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything more than it is possible.  Likely any such technology would be illegal and it's use subject to prosecution under the DMCA...

Comment: Ok, might stick a legally clause in the question.  Cheers Trey